# Canvas stretch image

Tags: node.js, canvas, discord.js

I just finished my rank system on my Discord bot, but someone with a low-resolution profile picture ran the command and it appears that the code does not stretch the image to fit, how can this be done? Also while I am here, perhaps you could take a look at my arc? I am not that great with canvas and the black border you see in the image is not exactly even all the way around, how would I change this to create the arc around the photo from the centre?
CODE:

```js
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(122.5, 141.8, 81, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.lineWidth = 6;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.save();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(
      message.author.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' }),
    );
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(avatar, 41.5, 60.5, 162, 162);
```

My PFP Output:[image]
Lower Res Output:[image]

Comment: The problem with stretching images is that they can get very pixelated

Comment: I would like the black circle border to be constant, so I can live with a pixelated image

Comment: the circle border `ctx.lineWidth = 6;` that looks about right on left image but on left one it seems the image is overlapping the circle, maybe move the drawing of the arc after you draw the image